# Rvalue reference parameter expires when passed via std::forward?

Tags: c++11, rvalue-reference

I have this code that attempts perfect forwarding of template parameters pack into `std::function` via intermediate class:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ...Arguments>
class CSignal
{
public:
    typedef std::function<void (Arguments...)> SignalFunction;
public:
    void connect(const SignalFunction& target)
    {
        m_connections.emplace_back(std::make_shared<SignalFunction>(target));
    }

    template <typename ...ActualArguments>
    void invoke(ActualArguments&&... args) const
    {
        for (auto& connection: m_connections)
            if (connection)
                (*connection)(std::forward<ActualArguments>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<SignalFunction>> m_connections;
};


struct A
{
    void f() {std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n";}
};

void test(std::shared_ptr<A> ptr)
{
    if (ptr)
        ptr->f();
}

int main()
{
    CSignal<std::shared_ptr<A>> signal;
    signal.connect(test);
    signal.connect(test);

    signal.invoke(std::make_shared<A>());

    return 0;
}
```

Problem: `test` is called twice, and the second time it's called its parameter is `empty` pointer. Why?

If I remove `std::forward` the issue disappears, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; `std::forward` does the same thing as `std::move` when `ActualArguments` is not a reference type.

In terms of expiration, `forward` needs to be treated the same as `move`. Generally you do not `forward` or `move` inside a loop.

If you want to move the parameter on the last loop iteration, you'll have to break it out of the loop. That probably means not using the range-for syntax. However, you might ask whether this is a worthwhile optimization, and consider saving it for later when more performance data are available.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, can you expand the answer? My understanding is that all `std::move` does is it returns its argument as rvalue reference, thus losing the parameter's name to actually make it an rvalue. But the original `args` parameter continues to exist in the outer scope (and it's an lvalue even if it was rvalue where `invoke` was called), why did it get destroyed? There's no move happening here per se, just parameter passing!

Comment: @VioletGiraffe `std::move` (and sometimes `std::forward`) causes its argument to be interpreted as an rvalue, which may cause expiration to happen inside a function which receives it specifically as an rvalue. The forward/move helper function generates a privilege which may be exercised by e.g. `test`. In this case, `test` always invalidates an rvalue argument.

Comment: OK, let's say I just want to make it work so I remove `std::forward`. Is there another wrapper that I should use instead?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Nope, the only straightforward solution here is simply to remove `forward`.